# Receiving HTTP 404 error when deleting project version in JIRA

Tags: c#, .net, jira, jira-rest-api

I am using the following code to delete a project version from a Jira database using the REST API:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = "DELETE";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

`url` is the `{self}` field of the version object and appears to be correct:

https://foobar.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/version/14455

where '14455' is the correct Jira ID of the version.

The user has proper permissions.

But the call returns 404 every time.

It appears from the [Jira documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/version) that this is the correct usage, so I'm thinking that there is something wrong with my code (this is not my field of expertise). Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

TIA

Comment: May be it doesn't exist. Have made sure that JiraID is correct?

Comment: No, it definitely exists, and the Jira ID is correct. I can put the same URL into Postman and it works. Something weird is going on here...

Comment: If you go to the `url` manually, in a browser, what do you get?

Comment: As long as I'm already logged in, I get a valid JSON response (since it's a GET operation and not DELETE, the JSON simply contains the issue fields). So I can use the browser to see the issue, and Postman or curl to delete it, all using the same URL That's why I figured there must be something wrong with my code.